# Why do I get this error on npm install in my angular project?

Tags: angular, npm

I have an Angular 7 project, and recently when I run `npm install` in my project I get this error:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: mat-silabo@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/core@7.1.4
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/core
npm ERR!   @angular/core@"~7.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/core@"^9.0.0 || ^10.0.0-0" from @angular/material-moment-   adapter@9.2.4
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/material-moment-adapter
npm ERR!   @angular/material-moment-adapter@"^9.1.2" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /home/userName/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/userName/.npm/_logs/2021-05-07T13_24_16_492Z-debug.log
```

It is a big project and I don't know how to resolve this package conflict. Here is my package.json file:

```json
{
  "name": "mat-silabo",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "~7.3.6",
    "@angular/common": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^7.0.0-beta.24",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/material": "^7.3.6",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^9.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "~7.1.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.2",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jspdf": "^1.5.3",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "xlsx": "^0.16.3",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.11.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.1.0",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.1.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.1.6"
  }
}
```

OS : Debian 10

Global Angular version : 11

If you need any other details please let me know. I am tired of this package dependency, and I want the project to be clean, so we can install it without `npm install --force`

thanks

Comment: Try looking through the error log. You'll see that NPM is complaining about a specific package "node_modules/@angular/material-moment-adapter" doesn't have a required peer of Angular 9. Your material-moment-adapter needs to be the same version as your Angular project. Currently, your material-moment-adapter is requesting Angular 9 as a peer dependency.

Answer (score 1):

It seems `"@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^9.1.2",` wants Angular 9 and you have Angular 7. Change this package to `"@angular/material-moment-adapter": "~7.1.0",` and do a fresh `npm install`. That should hopefully fix it.

Comment: thank you for your answer, I want to upgrade my application to version 11, but for now how I can keep all my packages versions fix

Comment: Pixelbits answered but yes, the `~` in front of the 7 will accept `c` upgrades only in `a.b.c` versioning and c upgrades should never break (minor bug fixes), b upgrades can have breaking changes and `a` upgrades are major upgrades and have breaking changes.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is complaining that it can't resolve @angular/core 9/10 which is a peer dependency of @angular/material-moment-adapter.

If you are upgrading to Angular 7, you should roll back this dependency to :

"@angular/material-moment-adapter": "~7.3.7"

Comment: Thank you very much, it works, but how I can prevent this type of errors?

Comment: Just make sure you use the semantic version upgrade policies: ^ = upgrade minor, ~ = upgrade patch, or in absence, use exact version.